# Splitting off one leg of a 20A 220v circuit for a plug - Is this to code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, nec

I want to avoid buying another breaker and using a slot up in my sub panel just for one plug.  I bought a plug\box kit which contains a 15A receptacle.  I assume this wouldn't be to code since the feed is 20A and the receptacle is rated for 15A.  If I get a 20A receptacle would I be able to wire in this manner?

I want to take one leg of the 220V feed to the pump motor, split it off, and go to a plug along with a neutral. Here is a diagram to explain.

[image]

Comment: all of the wiring must be rated for 20 amp (I don't know if there are other code issues)

Comment: Is the breaker for the pump a two-pole *common trip* type? Or is it two single pole breakers handle-tied together, or something else?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I believe a common trip.  It is a single breaker that contacts both bus bars and occupies two slots.  I assume two single poles are not to code where common trip is fine.

Comment: Do you already have the neutral at the pump location, or are you going to be pulling a new neutral wire (or new cable, depending on the wiring method)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - A plug box was previously installed and simply covered.  A neutral and ground were pulled to it from the subpanel.  The wires and box were covered.  Since I have to replace the pump timer anyway I was just going to pull a hot down to the plug from one of the inputs to the pump timer and install a 20A receptical .  The pump timer is basically a 220v relay.  The pump is not shown in the picture, only the inputs to the timer.

Comment: How much current does the pump pull btw?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Can't be too much.  1 HP = 746W.  P=IV (746/220)=3-4 A + 1A just in case (25%).  Since it's 220 it draws half the current of 110 for the same power.  I guess they put 20A circuits on these because peak draw when it starts up is pretty high.  I'm not worried about tripping a breaker since they won't be running at the same time..  I don't anticipate using the plug much anyway.  It's just a nice afterthought.

Comment: Using table 430.248 in the NEC, 1HP = 8A.

Comment: The existing wiring is 12AWG or thicker, right?

Comment: Is it *indeed* a 1 hp motor, like you read that off the nameplate?  Or did you make that up?

Comment: What is this pump for - a pool or jacuzzi or something else ? L1 will have an imbalanced load when a device is plugged into the plug. You already know that it will be possible to overload the circuit. The problem I have is that if this is a pool/jacuzzi pump of some sort - you might introduce an unintended current path when plugging a device in and that path could lead to the water being electrified.

Comment: @Harper - 1 HP sounds like a pool pump to me - so that would be fairly common, however the op should read the motor faceplate for proper info.

Answer (score 2):

### You're fine putting the receptacle there

You have a common-trip, two-pole breaker (instead of two handle-tied single pole breakers or an independent trip breaker), so that meets the disconnecting and OCP requirements for a mixed 120/240V circuit (210.4(C) Exception 2), and since the motor FLA is only 8A, it doesn't exceed the 50% (10A) limit on hardwired loads where receptacles or luminaires are also present (210.23(A)(2)).

Since the breaker is 20A and this will no longer be a motor-only circuit, not only do you need to use 12AWG wire for the connection to the new receptacle, you need to make sure the existing wiring is all 12AWG or thicker, and replace any substandard wire found.  Also, make sure the motor has a built-in thermal overload protector or is impedance protected as per 430.32(B) and 430.53(B). (Look for a red button on the motor, or the letters 'T.P.' or 'Z.P.' on the motor nameplate.)